# Sudden drops in matrix multiplication performance

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, blas

I've been reading about implementing dense matrix multiplication when the matrix doesn't fit in cache. One of the graphs I've seen (slide 9 from [these slides](http://vuduc.org/teaching/standalone-talks/mem-hier-tutorial-1.pdf)) shows sudden drops in performance using the naive algorithm. This drops are to around 50% of the speed, occur while the matrix still fits in cache, and only occur for one or two sizes. I'm not planning on using the naive algorithm, but I would like to know where the sudden drops in performance come from. (The drops also occur with blocked algorithms, but are much smaller.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a classic example of cache associativity. The stride associated with that problem size is filling up certain sets causing cache eviction despite there being lots of space in other sets.

[image: Cache associativity]

Figure from [Gustavo Duarte's excellent blog post](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/intel-cpu-caches) on the topic

See also [Drepper's *What every programmer should know about memory*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf).